# What kind of enhancement is this (FORM USEREXIT_*), and how do I implement such an enhancement

Tags: include, abap, subroutine, sap-erp

I have an include RV60AFZZ, and a form USEREXIT_NUMBER_RANGE.

On one system, this form contains an addition

```
*{   INSERT         ASDF555555                                      1
  "Custom code here...
  ....
*}   INSERT
```

...and in another system the form contains just 2 commented lines, with no *{ INSERT and *} INSERT

I want to know how to implement such an enhancement on my other system, or more noobishly : How to write code in that include that's not in the customer namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you by any chance work on a Netweaver system with an Enhancement package you could enhance this user exit form by using an implicit enhancement instead of requesting the object key to modify this subroutine.

Comment: This was it, actually. I found that i indeed could create an implicit enhancement implementation - didn't know about those things before. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an enhancement, it's a modification. Avoid it at all costs, unless you really have no other choice. It's a road that leads straight to maintenance hell.

The pseudo-comments are generated by the [Modification Assistant](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04s/helpdata/en/60/d6ba5aceda11d1953a0000e82de14a/frameset.htm). You can turn it off, but prepare to get shot by your customers/colleagues for a very good reason if you do so. :-)

Comment: I kindly disagree, maybe it is a modification per se but this is just the old way SAP let their customer extend the code. It is called User Exit and is simply a form for which you have to get an object key from the Service Marketplace anyway. It was introduced when the BAdIs and BTEs, not to mention EHPs were not even existing.

Comment: @Jagger: That's no reason not to avoid it at all costs :-)

Comment: I agree, however sometimes there is no other way, especially if one is working with an older version of SAP system that comes from before the Netweaver era.

Comment: Modifications are still occasionally necessary, however there is never a good reason to turn of Modification Assistant.